# JSP getAttribute() returning null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

So in my Servlet I have the following:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        req.setAttribute("colNames","ka");
        req.setAttribute("items", new String[]{});
        //System.out.println(req.getAttribute("colNames"));
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req,resp);
}
```

My Servlet:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>NewGem OrderInfo</title>
    <script src="sorttable.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<%= request.getAttribute("colNames") %>
<table id="table" class="sortable">
    <tr>
        <c:forEach items="${param.colNames}" var="col">
            <td>${col}</td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${param.items}" var="row">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach items="${row.elements()}" var="value">
            <td>${value}</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <display-name>EntityDumpServlet</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>dump</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EntityDumpServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.jpmorgan.d1.ptg.web.EntityDumpServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EntityDumpServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dump</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

So I'm just running the get, have only this servlet nothing else.

I know that I should use JSTL and I am, but this was my way of checking that it was not a JSTL problem but some what a java problem. Anyone have any ideas?

PS: If I do just `<%= request %>` I get `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@58c3fbeb` so the problem is not in not casting the result to String.
And if I do on the servlet `System.out.println(req);` I get `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4ac37ce2`, which means for some reason the request passed and received are different?

Result: It turned out that for some reason the IDE is doing some weird stuff and introduced this problem in the forwarding. When I deployed it on with maven compiled WAR file on the tomcat it worked okay.

Comment: try a simple string first to know if problem is with your array or with dispatching

Comment: Can you show your actual code with exact flow.

Comment: Still null, its a dispatch problem, but I can't figure any way of approaching it.

Comment: are you redirected to index.php , it's where you got null value ?Show us your jsp page

Comment: I added the exact code executed.

Comment: @Belov Did you try my answer, did it help?

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately nope. Is my web.xml ok?

Comment: @Belov Your colNames is a String or an array of String --> String[] ?

Comment: I've treid with String[], didn't work out and for simplicity changed it to just String.

Comment: @Belov Edited my answer, just check if it helps. You are using froEach, for displaying a String?

Comment: oh that code is from the time when I had a String[], but even then colNames were not there

Answer (score 8):

You are not typecasting it to String.
`request.getAttribute()` will return an `Object`.

Try using this and see if it works:

```
String value = (String)request.getAttribute("colnames");
```

Or

```
<%= (String)request.getAttribute("colNames") %>
```

Why are you using `forEach` here? You just need to display a `String` right?
Also, shouldn't `var="col"` **be ------>** `var = "colNames"`

```
     <tr>
        <c:forEach items="${param.colNames}" var="col">
            <td>${col}</td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use,

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("colNames",yourObject);
```

To persist it through the request/response and then pull it out of the session on your JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue with the tomcat server 7. I updated it to 8.5 and its working fine now.