# href attribute of a li element coming up as null when there is data for the href

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to iterate over a collection of li elements in an ordered list and then print the URL from each element.

The HTML:

```
<div id="global-atoz-navigation">
  <nav role="navigation" aria-label="Suppliers">
    <ol>


          <li class="selected">
            <span class="visuallyhidden">Suppliers starting with </span>
            <strong>A</strong>
          </li>



          <li>
            <span class="visuallyhidden">Suppliers starting with </span>
            <a href="/g-cloud/suppliers?prefix=B">B</a>
          </li>



          <li>
            <span class="visuallyhidden">Suppliers starting with </span>
            <a href="/g-cloud/suppliers?prefix=C">C</a>
          </li>
</ol>
</nav>
</div>
```

My code so far:

```
WebElement navDiv = driver.findElement(By.id("global-atoz-navigation"));
List<WebElement> links = navDiv.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (WebElement link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));

}
```

But for some reason this is printing 'null' for each li element. Any ideas why?

Comment: Perhaps because there are no `li` tags with `href` attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<li>` elements don't have an `href` attribute. The `<a>` elements inside them do. Is there a reason you wouldn't do `navDiv.findElements(By.tagName("a"))` to find those instead? Or, if there could be anchors you want to avoid, either get all the anchors and filter the bad ones out, or get all the list items and do another `li.findElements(By.tagName("a"))` on each one.

Please note that `<li>` isn't short for "link". It's short for "list item".

Links are in the "anchor", or `<a>`, element.

Comment: Thanks, changed it to find the <a> element and not the list items. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Referencing from the answer here:

[JSP getAttribute() returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490517/jsp-getattribute-returning-null)

"You are not typecasting it to String.  `request.getAttribute()` will return an Object."

Try using this and see if it works:

```
String value = (String)link.getAttribute("href");
```

What's also true is ErikE's answer where you should be grabbing the attributes for the < a > tags not the < li > tags